# AMD bulldozer on XEN server

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, xen

I'm planning to setup an home server for testing purposes, therefore I going to
need a lot of power, and I was wondering if Xen Server supports the new 
AMD Bulldozer architecture(which has 8 physical core)? Has anyone tried yet?

Comment: Xen works just fine on servers with 8-core Intel CPUs that I've set up in the past.  I installed Xen on NetBSD (Unix) using this guide (which I wrote a few years ago):  http://www.lumbercartel.ca/library/xen/

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason it shouldn't work - bulldozer should support the same range of virtualisation extensions that its predecessors did and its a fairly standard x86 based system. The OS under which Xen Server runs easily handles 8 cores (or more).

Support for the on die video - since the bulldozer is an APU, might lag, but it will be supported at some point

Comment: Ok I understand and thanks a lot for your help, even though I still have a lot of concerns about compatibly among XenServer and the motherboard that I'm planning to buy, which comes with a 990fx chipset and they don't have any discrete graphic card integrated. If anyone has any idea on how to manage this scenario please let me know!